# Build error in Xcode by react-native code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

This is my error:

```
Build system information

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/tanhaeirad/Project/Rahanj/RezasPortal/portalapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/portalapp.app/AntDesign.ttf':
1) Target 'portalapp' (project 'portalapp') has copy command from '/Users/tanhaeirad/Project/Rahanj/RezasPortal/portalapp/node_modules/native-base/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/tanhaeirad/Project/Rahanj/RezasPortal/portalapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/portalapp.app/AntDesign.ttf'
2) Target 'portalapp' (project 'portalapp') has copy command from '/Users/tanhaeirad/Project/Rahanj/RezasPortal/portalapp/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/tanhaeirad/Project/Rahanj/RezasPortal/portalapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/portalapp.app/AntDesign.ttf'
```

but my code run in simulator
i code with react native and this error shown when i install react-native base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, go to < one of the library target names > => Build Phases => Copy Bundle Resources and remove the font that's causing the issue. This should ensure that it only gets copied into the app package once. It probably doesn't matter which of those two libraries you remove it from.

Comment: I've deleted some old fonts and was getting this error. Your comment solved it for me. Thanks.

CpResource /PATH/MaisonNeue-ThinItalic.ttf /PATH/MaisonNeue-ThinItalic.ttf (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppName')